# Why can my Python MySQLdb script see, but not make live changes to, my database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am working with a customized Django installation, although the issue I am dealing with is from a command line tool intended to update the database. The tool reads the database as intended and functions comparably to typing SELECTs in MySQL's command line. However, it seems never to *change* the database. I tried a few variations, including a trial run of just `execute()`ing the literal query I want for trial purposes, but it doesn't do anything, failing without reported exception or error. The MySQL command line handles updates predictably well.

My code, both including the read-oriented code that works and the write-oriented code that silently fails, is (in sanitized form):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import sys

connection = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd="_______________")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE _____________')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'check': # This seems to work
        username = sys.argv[2]
        cursor.execute(
          '''SELECT username, foo FROM auth_user WHERE username = %s''',
          [username])
        for result in cursor:
            print 'Username: ' + result[0]
            print 'Foo: ' + str(result[1])
    if sys.argv[1] == 'set': # This seems to function as a noop
        username = sys.argv[2]
        foo = int(sys.argv[3])
        cursor.execute('UPDATE auth_user SET foo = ' + str(foo) + 
          " WHERE username = '" + username.replace("'", "\\'") + "'")
```

What other steps should I be doing to update the field foo on the given row? The update query is deliberately dumbed-down SQL, but I don't want to focus on sophistication before I even have the literal version working.

Thanks,

Comment: You have a correct answer below, but I wonder why you're doing all this via direct SQL rather than using your Django models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit data

```
    cursor.execute('UPDATE auth_user SET foo = ' + str(foo) + " WHERE username = '" + username.replace("'", "\\'") + "'")
    connection.commit()
```

Take a look at [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) to get more information